How to read geometry and dimension data from an IFC file using ifcopenshellÉ
In the project I am currently working on, I have a task to use an IFC file to read data and save it in a database. I am using ifcopenshell to read the data. However, in the IFC file, I could not figure out how to get the geometry and dimension data. Can anyone help me with this, please?

def extract_geometry(entity):
    geometry_data = []

    if hasattr(entity, 'Representation'):
        representation = entity.Representation
        for item in \
            (representation.Items if representation.Items else []):
            if hasattr(item, 'Representation'):
                geometry_data.append({'type': item.is_a(),
                        'geometry_data': item.Representation.get_info()})  # Get geometry data

    return geometry_data


def parse_ifc_structure(ifc_file_path, type):
    ifc_file = ifcopenshell.open(ifc_file_path)
    entities_data = []

    for entity in ifc_file.by_type(type):

        entity_data = {
            'id': entity.id(),
            'global_id': (entity.GlobalId if hasattr(entity, 'GlobalId'
                          ) else None),
            'LongName': (entity.LongName if hasattr(entity, 'LongName'
                         ) else None),
            'Name': (entity.Name if hasattr(entity, 'Name') else None),
            'Phase': (entity.Phase if hasattr(entity, 'Phase'
                      ) else None),
            'CompositionType': (entity.CompositionType if hasattr(entity,
                                'CompositionType') else None),
            'type': entity.is_a(),
            'geometry': extract_geometry(entity),
            'Representation': (entity.Representation if hasattr(entity,
                               'Representation') else None),
            'ObjectPlacement': (entity.Representation if hasattr(entity,
                                'ObjectPlacement') else None),
            }

            # "Placement": entity.Representation if hasattr(entity, "Placement") else None,

        entities_data.append(entity_data)

    return entities_data

This is the code I have but extract_geometry does not retrieve the values (x,y,z) mentioned in the screen shot.
